# How to get all combinations satisfying a condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given a table, Table, with columns N1, N2, N3, how can I get all combinations satisfying the condition N1 + N2 + N3 > 10?

For example, querying the table:

```
       N1      N2      N3
Row1   1       5       4
Row2   4       4       3
```

Should give the result:

```
       N1      N2      N3
Row1   4       5       4
Row2   4       4       4
Row3   4       4       3
Row3   4       5       3
```

How can I do this in T-SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it but something like this should work. Cross join will give you all the combinations and you filter them to return only those which satisfy your condition. `DISTINCT` is there to filter duplicate combinations which may occur if i.e. all three columns have the same value in one row.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.N1, T2.N2, T3.N3
FROM
    (SELECT N1 FROM YourTable) AS T1
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT N2 FROM YourTable) AS T2
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT N3 FROM YourTable) AS T3
WHERE T1.N1 + T2.N2 + T3.N3 > 10;
```

Comment: The nested selects in this example are unnecessary, Ed Harper's syntax is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you want all the combinations of N1, N2 and N3 which add up to > 10, regardless of which row the values occur on.

```
create table #t
(N1 int
,N2 int
,N3 int
)


insert #t
select 1,5,4
union select 4,4,3


select n1.N1, n2.N2, n3.N3
from #t as n1
cross join #t as n2
cross join #t as n3
where n1.N1 + n2.N2 + n3.N3 > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the very few examples of when a Cartesian product is a valid answer.

My query that I tried is as follows:

```
select distinct t1.t1, t2.t2, t3.t3
from test t1, test t2, test t3
where (t1.t1 + t2.t2 + t3.t3) > 10
```

I'm not familiar with the Cross Join syntax, but both seem to work fine.

Edit: I found this argument for the 'Join' syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128965/is-there-something-wrong-with-joins-that-don't-use-the-join-keyword-in-sql-or-mys

Comment: It's a more modern syntax is all. Specifying no join (as you have done) gives the same result - the Cartesian product, as you say. If for example you had three tables joined A inner B cross C, you would prefer to say cross explicitly to show you know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks AakashM. For other readers I deleted the first comment asking about why you would use the Cross Join and added a link.