# SQL assistance with the WHERE clause. Getting an error for the following code

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi guys I am trying to create a query to display employee name and employee number along with their super’s name and super’s number. Listing also includes employees who don’t have any supervisor. I wrote a bit of code for it and it gives me and error because its not right. 
Would anyone be kind enough to give me a hand with this. Cheers guys

```
SELECT employee.ename, employee.empno, boss.ename, boss.empno
FROM   emp employee, emp boss
WHERE  employee.super = boss.empno 
OR     employee.super AND boss.empno IS NULL;
```

Thanks in advance

-Jay

Allright guys I found the answer and I used outer join operator. The left join works but we are not taught that in our course. Thanks for that. The answer using the outer join is as follows:

```
SELECT employee.ename, employee.empno, boss.ename, boss.empno
FROM   emp employee, emp boss
WHERE  employee.super = boss.empno(+);
```

So it will still return rows that has null for employee.super.

Comment: You want a 'left outer join'.

Comment: @Steward, left join is not the same as an equi-inner join that joins on `(a=b or (a is null and b is null))` the left join will also produce a a-row _(for want of a better moniker)_ on `a=something and b is null`, the latter join will not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT employee.ename, employee.empno, boss.ename, boss.empno
FROM emp employee
LEFT JOIN emp boss
ON employee.super = boss.empno
```

The `LEFT JOIN` means that every row in the left table (employee) will be returned, even if there is no matching row in the right table (boss).

Comment: Good one bro! works fine but I forgot to add I can only use outer join. So I uploaded my answer after I found it

Comment: @Jay: `LEFT JOIN` **is** an outer join, you can also use: `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use implicit SQL '89 join syntax, it's an anti-pattern.
Get out of jurassic park and use explicit SQL '92 join syntax:

```
SELECT 
  employee.ename
  , employee.empno
  , boss.ename
  , boss.empno 
FROM   emp employee
INNER JOIN emp boss on (employee.super <=> boss.empno)
```

You can use the `<=>` operator:

```
null = null   -> null  -> no join
1 = 1         -> true  -> join
1 = 0         -> false -> no join

null <=> null -> true  -> join
1 <=> 1       -> true  -> join
1 <=> 0       -> false -> no join
```

`<=>` is MySQL specific, outside of MySQL you'd use: 
 `(e.super = b.empno or (e.super is null and b.empno is null))`

Note that above join is not the same as a left join:

```
//code from Mark Byers' answer
SELECT employee.ename, employee.empno, boss.ename, boss.empno 
FROM emp employee 
LEFT JOIN emp boss 
ON employee.super = boss.empno
```

The inner join produces fewer rows.

***Disclaimer:*** The following link is a quick and dirty visualisation of joins, to be taken with a grain of salt. But it does visualize the general idea.
See: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: "null = null -> false" -- I'm assuming you've made a misstatement, rather than MySQL having dodgy three-valued logic. In Standard SQL, `null = null` should evaluate to UNKNOWN.

Comment: @onedaywhen, It's not a misstatement, for the purpose of the join, the outcome is either join (stated as `true`) or no-join (stated as `false`). Will rephase the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Remaining issues (which I don't expect you will correct :) Old style inner joins are just a matter of taste, not an "anti-pattern". The pictures you linked to I think tend to confuse more than clarify e.g. the first picture depicts `A INTERSECT B`, second picture is `A UNION B`, the third picture is simply `A`, etc.

Comment: @onedaywhen, implicit joins are an official anti-pattern. One if's or buts about it. The fact that the machine understands them does not make then useful for humans. The same problem exists with `goto` it's very useful, works like a charm yet still a clear anti-pattern. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128965/is-there-something-wrong-with-joins-that-dont-use-the-join-keyword-in-sql-or-mys

Comment: @onedaywhen, I would love to have a better link to explain joins, the sloppyness in the article has been bugging me for a while, unfortunatly I don't have a good link that's easy to grok.

Comment: "official anti-pattern" -- I'm not sure that you can convince me of that and I'm certainly not convinced by reading that thread. The main thrust of the most popular answer is IMO wrong: most optimizers will recognise the inner join from the old style syntax, as one of the answers demonstrates using SQL Server. Even Bill Karwin, who literally [wrote the book on SQL antipattern](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) stops short of condemning the old style syntax in his answer there :) Bottom line: product and restriction are basic relational operations that can't be outlawed.

Comment: @onedaywhen, I agree that the accepted answer is actually the worst answer, such is life. It's an anti-pattern because: A: it makes it hard to spot messing join criteria (inner joins make that easy); B: explicit joins force you to group the join criteria per table that you join, with implicit joins you can mix and match making code hard to understand. C: implicit joins put everything in the where clause, agian hindering understanding D: switching between left and inner joins is **hard** with implicit joins but trivial with explicit joins E: see below:

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4066/discussion-between-johan-and-onedaywhen)

Answer (score 1):

You have used `employee.super` and it is trying to be evaluated as a boolean in:

```
OR     employee.super AND boss.empno IS NULL;
```

You need to be comparing it to something.

I would use:

```
SELECT employee.ename, employee.empno, boss.ename, boss.empno 
FROM   emp employee
LEFT JOIN emp boss ON employee.super = boss.empno
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT employee.ename, employee.empno, boss.ename, boss.empno, CASE WHEN boss.empno IS NULL THEN 'no supervisor found'
                                                                    ELSE 'supervisor found'
                                                                END
  FROM employee LEFT JOIN emp boss ON boss.empno = employee.super
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employee.ename, employee.empno, boss.ename, boss.empno
FROM   emp employee, emp boss
WHERE  employee.super = boss.empno
UNION
SELECT employee.ename, employee.empno, '(no boss)', ('no boss')
FROM   emp employee
WHERE  employee.super IS NULL;
```