# Difference between using Join query with other in sqlserver stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have seen some queries with different methods:

```
 Method 1:
    select A.col1,A.col2,B.col1,B.col2 
    from tblA A,tblB B
    where A.ID=B.ID

Method 2:
select A.col1,A.col2,B.col1,B.col2 
from tblA A join tblB B on A.ID=B.ID
```

*What is the difference between these two queries or advantage of using one on other?*
if we use just `JOIN` keyword instead of `INNER JOIN/OUTER JOIN/LEFT JOIN` which join it is to be called?

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` means `INNER JOIN`.

Check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128965/is-there-something-wrong-with-joins-that-dont-use-the-join-keyword-in-sql-or-my), especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/129006/357313).

Comment: thanks @Michel de Ruiter for replying. So, what should we use Method1 or Method2 preferably? I think we should go for Method2 right?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE I certainly do. It's been introduced long ago for a reason. The comma notation is for backwards compatibility only.