# Documentum Query Language Inner Join

Tags: sql, inner-join, dql, documentum

I'm working with DQL queries but don't have access to the EMC resources, and I'm new to development in general with some experience in SQL. I want to do an INNER JOIN between two tables, but can only do a LEFT JOIN for some reason. I've noticed others using a Cartesian join (dm_table_1, dm_table_2)-- is that the syntax for DQL inner join? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AHiggins wrote a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25270330/3472757)

```
SELECT *
FROM dm_table1,dm_table2
WHERE dm_table1.id = dm_table2.id
```

is the way you implicitly write inner join. This is possible even in older versions of Documentum. However, from version 6.7 above you can use explicitly write LEFT OUTER JOIN too. You can read more details about it under *Source lists* section in DQL Reference guide available at [this](https://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jouvinio.net%2Fwiki%2Fimages%2F2%2F2c%2FDocumentum_Content_Server_6.7_DQL_Reference.pdf&ei=mHDqU5nPNpCe7Ab14oDoCQ&usg=AFQjCNF63-kvuzyHadzAzLOVgyflhaMyyA&sig2=9ahf8IEKB5nBhc-zr7QYqg&bvm=bv.72938740,bs.1,d.bGE&cad=rja) link.

[EMC support forums](https://community.emc.com/search.jspa?q=dql%20inner%20join) are open and you can find lots of answers there.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I've seen some of the EMC support forums before via google searches, but I didn't realize they own and support Documentum.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any specific understanding of Documentum, but in most SQL languages when you use a [comma-style JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128965/is-there-something-wrong-with-joins-that-dont-use-the-join-keyword-in-sql-or-my), you generally add the 'JOIN condition' to the WHERE clause.

So, you'd use

```
FROM dm_table1,dm_table2
WHERE dm_table1.id = dm_table2.id
```

Comment: thanks! found out that DQL does not have inner join, and this is the only way to mimic the same functionality.