# How to perform a complex SQL query on DataTable objects?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, datatable, in-memory-database

I am programming an Excel add-in in C# where I process data contained in different `DataTable` objects. I would like to provide a function to perform SQL queries on the data, with the ability to reference data from other tables in where and sort by clauses (for example, using a join).

An example of such a query would be

```
SELECT name
FROM Table1
WHERE id = Table2.id AND Table2.age > 18
```

The problem with this is that a `DataTable` doesn't know of the existance of the other `DataTable`s, so (for so far I know) there are no such methods in the class. Also, I cannot use something like LINQ, since the query will be written by the users of the add-in in excel.

Would it be a good solution to copy the data to an in-memory database, where each `DataTable` is mapped to a table? How would this work performance-wise? Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: A SQL query always returns one flat table so there is never an existence of other tables.  Either you  need to use a join in the SQL Query to combine tables, or the queries you already perform have a common field(s) that you can use Linq to join.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of SQL query you are missing a table reference in selecting the tables, corrected query will look like

```
SELECT name
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id AND Table2.age > 18
```

Use `Table1.name` if there is same named attribute in `Table2`.
However using only `WHERE` condition in Joins without specifying the joining attribute is not recommended [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128965/is-there-something-wrong-with-joins-that-dont-use-the-join-keyword-in-sql-or-my). Use `JOIN`.

```
SELECT Table1.name
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id WHERE Table2.age > 18
```