# SQL Server working with 2 tables (foreign key?) ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables in my SQL Server database, using Visual Studio 2013:

1. Category

   - Id
   - Name
2. Product

   - Id
   - Name
   - CategoryId

I have a Product Page built in ASP.NET (webforms) in which I can Create, Edit or Delete Products.

I made a connection (foreign key) between the 2 tables.

I want to display my products and instead of having the Category as a number (Id) I want to have it`s name.

How should I do it?

My knowledge in SQL is pretty basic.

This is how I`m displaying the code, using a DataList:

```
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM Products;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);

dlProducts.DataSource = ds;
dlProducts.DataBind();
```

Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Your query could look like this:

```
select *
from products p -- p is an "alias" for the table products
inner join category c on p.categoryId = c.id -- here we're specifying that the products table to join onto the category table via their relationship columns.
```

Note the above will return more columns than what you require, you can change the `*` to only return the columns needed (and it's normally considered better to specify a column list)

Answer (score 2):

Join to the categories table, and return the name from the categories table along with the main result.

```
string SQL = "SELECT p.*, pc.Name FROM Products p
              INNER JOIN ProductCategories pc
              ON p.ProductCategoryID = pc.ProductCategoryID;";
```

Comment: I want to thank the all of you guys!
Thank you alot really!!

Answer (score 1):

Change your select statement into this:

```
"SELECT p.Id, p.Name, c.Name FROM Product p, Category c WHERE p.CategoryId=c.Id;"
```

Comment: while this looks like it would technically work, I believe comma "joins" are generally frowned upon as they are an older syntax and inefficient.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/129410/2312877 for more info.  Though there is some debate on the inneficiency of it as well :)