# SQL Same Values but different secondary values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

I've tried this for hours and different forums but cant get my head around to figure out this. I've tried joins and all sorts but i constantly got wrong results.

My sample table looks like below

```
Item Branch  Type
A    Main    Box
A    London  Single
A    Paris   Single
A    Tokyo   Box
B    Main    Single
B    London  Single
B    Paris   Single
C    Main    Single
C    London  Box
C    Paris   Single
C    Tokyo   Single
D    Main    Box
D    London  Single
D    Paris   Box
D    Tokyo   Box
D    Sydney  Single
```

what I want to get as my result set is all Items that has a Different 'Type' to its **Main** 'Branch'

For example if Main Type is Box, display Main branch and other branches that has different Types

result table should look like below.

```
Item Branch  Type
**A    Main    Box**
A    London  Single
A    Paris   Single
**C    Main    Single**
C    London  Box
**D    Main    Box**
D    London  Single
D    Sydney  Single
```

any help is much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: *"I've tried joins and all sorts..."* There are a lot of helpful people on SO who won't bother to answer unless you *show* what you've tried. You're also likely to get more responses if you include CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Why aren't any records from Item B included in the results?

Comment: @destination-data Hi Any records from B aren't in results because 'B's are in same type as its main branch in all other branches
whereas other items are present a different type in other branches. hope this explains it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it to get the rows where the type on any branch differs from the main branch.

```
select * 
from t t1 
where (branch='Main' or (branch <> 'Main' 
                         and exists (select 1 from t 
                                     where item=t1.item and branch = 'Main' 
                                     and type <> t1.type)
                         )
       )
and item in (select item from t group by item having count(distinct type) > 1)
```

If the query above seems confusing, you can use a cte to get all the non - main branches whose type differs from the main branch for an item. Thereafter use `union all` to get the main branch rows for those items.

```
with y as (
select * from t t1
where branch <> 'Main' and exists (select 1 from t 
                                   where item=t1.item and branch = 'Main' 
                                   and type <> t1.type)
    )
select * from t where branch='Main' and item in (select item from y)
union all
select * from y
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much for this. it works perfect!!
I tried the, 
nested select query
bit as separate query and tried joining it with the big table but I got confused trying to match columns and how to name them etc. also I discovered the Count function from other similar posts but never could get my head around to bring all these together.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.item, A.branch, A.type 
from ibt A, ibt B 
on A.item = B.item and B.branch = "Main" and A.type != B.type;
```

the results are as blow:

```
A|London|Single
A|Paris|Single
C|London|Box
D|London|Single
D|Sydney|Single
```

Comment: There's a great discussion in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128965/is-there-something-wrong-with-joins-that-dont-use-the-join-keyword-in-sql-or-my) on the older style of join you've used in your example.  Tl;dr Avoid them.  Use ANSI joins instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood what you need.
However, here is a possible partial solution.
You can improve this simple with your requirement.

Sample in postgre.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY  TABLE items (
  item varchar(10),
  branch varchar(10),
  type varchar(10)
);


INSERT INTO items VALUES ('A', 'Main', 'Box');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('A', 'London', 'Single');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('A', 'Paris', 'Single');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('A', 'Tokyo', 'Box');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('B', 'Main', 'Single');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('B', 'London', 'Single');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('B', 'Paris', 'Single');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('C', 'Main', 'Single');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('C', 'London', 'Box');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('C', 'Paris', 'Single');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('C', 'Tokyo', 'Single');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('D', 'Main', 'Box');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('D', 'London', 'Single');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('D', 'Paris', 'Box');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('D', 'Tokyo', 'Box');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('D', 'Sydney', 'Single');

SELECT
CASE WHEN T.branch = 'Main' THEN rpad(T.item, length(T.item) + T.children::INT, '*') ELSE T.item END item,
T.branch,
T.type
FROM (
SELECT
  I.item,
  I.branch,
  I.type,
  MAIN_ITEMS.item                              mitem,
  MAIN_ITEMS.branch                            mbranch,
  MAIN_ITEMS.type                              mtype,
  (SELECT count(j.item)
   FROM items j
   WHERE I.ITEM = j.item AND I.type <> j.type) children    FROM items I
  JOIN (
         SELECT
           item,
           branch,
           type
         FROM items
         WHERE branch = 'Main'

       ) MAIN_ITEMS
    ON ((I.ITEM = MAIN_ITEMS.item AND I.type <> MAIN_ITEMS.type) OR (
    I.ITEM = MAIN_ITEMS.item AND I.branch = MAIN_ITEMS.branch AND I.type = MAIN_ITEMS.type
  )
    )
) T
where T.children > 0;
```

Output:

```
A** Main    Box
A   London  Single
A   Paris   Single
C*  Main    Single
C   London  Box
D** Main    Box
D   London  Single
D   Sydney  Single
```

I hope that this sample help you.