# SQL- INNER JOIN use makes me confused

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm learning SQL, and I've just learned about inner joins. The thing is, I'd been taught some other way to join tables before, and I don't understand the difference

For example, the way I already knew:

```
SELECT E.SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES E, DEPARTMENTS D
WHERE E.DP = D.DP AND D.CITY = 'LONDON';
```

This would show the salary of the employees that work on a department located in London

Now, the other way, using join:

```
SELECT E.SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES E
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON D.CITY = 'LONDON'
AND D.DP = E.DP;
```

EDIT: I've since edited the question, as I left out some of the code for the example. Sorry for the confusion, everyone

What's the difference between the two? Wouldn't both examples show the employees working in a department in London? Thanks

I've looked up in w3schools the JOIN clause, but still didn't understand what would be the difference between those two ways

Comment: 1. - just don't use W3schools - ever. 2. read [bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) (applies equally to mysql and other sql products)

Comment: Yeah w3schools -- friends don't let friends.

Comment: a comma seperated from means a cross join and your where reduces that cross join to an inner join

Comment: WHERE E.DP_D.DP - no idea what this might mean..

Comment: 1. Why not use w3schools? Just curious
2. Thanks, nbk, will search cross joins
3. P.Salmon, thanks for noticing that. I've edited the question, meant to write "="

Comment: *Why not use w3schools* Because it's usually incomplete, out of date, misleading or just plain wrong - not great if you are just learning. It's not called W3Fools for nothing ;-)

Comment: You might find this thread explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128965/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example (modified from your orginal statement) ...

1. `SELECT E.SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES E, DEPARTMENTS D WHERE D.CITY='LONDON';`

... will produce the same results as ...

2. `SELECT E.SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES E INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON D.CITY='LONDON';`

or even ...

3. `SELECT E.SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES E INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D WHERE D.CITY='LONDON';`

But the first example, which uses an obsolete syntax, should not be used in modern code. You run the risk of one day it not being supported and then your code stops working. It is also less clear than the other two examples.

By the way, the 2nd and 3rd SQL statements only produce the same results *in general* because an *inner join* is being performed. You will in general get different results from using the `ON` condition vs. the `WHERE` clause if you were doing an *outer join*.

**But I am not sure any of these statements will produce your desired results.**

You will be returned *every* row from `EMPLOYEES` multiple times, once for each row in `DEPARTMENTS` where the city is London. Perhaps you mean something like:

`SELECT E.SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES E INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON D.CITY='LONDON' AND D.DEPARTMENT_NUMBER = E.DEPARTMENT_NUMBER`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
It was just an example to learn from, but I tried it and it didn't return multiple times every row from employees. May be because of the version I'm using. Thank you
EDIT: Yes, I meant that. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I see you have updated your post specifying `E.DP=D.DP` as another condition. Then you will get what you want. But your original code had something that did not make any sense and so the modified version I had will produce what I said.

Comment: Appreciate it. Your answer was very clear, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is this:

```sql
SELECT E.SALARY 
  FROM EMPLOYEES E, DEPARTMENTS D WHERE E.DP = D.DP
   AND D.CITY='LONDON';
```

It can be rewritten, without changing its meaning, as an inner JOIN like this:

```sql
     SELECT E.SALARY 
       FROM EMPLOYEES E
 INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON E.DP = D.DP
      WHERE D.CITY='LONDON';
```

Your first example uses your grandmother's (really!) SQL comma-join syntax.  In SQL-92 the explicit JOIN syntax was standardized.

If you say this, without `E.DP = D.DP`, you get all possible pairs of rows in the two tables. That's called a cross join. It's very rarely what you want.

```sql
SELECT E.SALARY 
  FROM EMPLOYEES E, DEPARTMENTS D 
 WHERE D.CITY='LONDON';
```

This, an inner join without an ON-clause, gets you the same large and probably useless cross-join result.

```sql
     SELECT E.SALARY 
       FROM EMPLOYEES E
 INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D 
      WHERE D.CITY='LONDON';
```

Inner joins remove all rows from the result set that don't match the ON clause. You can use a LEFT JOIN if you want to keep the rows from the first table that have no match in the second table.  This gets you all employees, including those that aren't assigned to any department.

```sql
     SELECT E.SALARY 
       FROM EMPLOYEES E
  LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON E.DP = D.DP
      WHERE D.CITY='LONDON';
```

In the industry we like using the newer JOIN syntax because it makes LEFT JOIN operations much more straightforward to write. (RIGHT JOIN also exists, but we don't use it much.)

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer! I've edited the question since, I meant to write e.dp=d.dp on the join too, but forgot